# Routing issue while hosting application on Nginx with Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I have developed Laravel 5.1 application on XAMPP installed on Windows 8 environment. Now I want to deploy it using Nginx installed on Ubuntu 14 environment.

I have performed all the configurations mentioned in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04. I can access all site routes e.g. Home, About, Contact without any issues.

But there is an issue while accessing auth routes. e.g. when I clicked on login, instead of authentication it gets redirected to analytics/sales with "InvalidArgumentException in compiled.php" error stating "View [analytics.sales.index] not found."

This is not the case with Windows 8 environment and application works perfectly on windows 8.

My route file:

```
<?php

/****************   Model binding into rout  ********************/

Route::model('user', 'App\User');
Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('slug', '[0-9a-z-_]+');

/***************    Site routes  **********************************/
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('home', array('as' => 'home' , 'uses' =>    'HomeController@index'));
Route::get('about', array('as' => 'about', 'uses' =>'PagesController@about'));
Route::get('contact', array('as' => 'contact', 'uses' =>  'PagesController@contact'));


 Route::controllers([
'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);


 /***************    Admin routes  **********************************/
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function()   
{

  # Admin Dashboard
  Route::get('dashboard', 'Admin\DashboardController@index');


  # Users
  Route::get('user/data', 'Admin\UserController@data');
  Route::get('user/{user}/show', 'Admin\UserController@show');
  Route::get('user/{user}/edit', 'Admin\UserController@edit');
  Route::get('user/{user}/delete', 'Admin\UserController@delete');
  Route::resource('user', 'Admin\UserController');
  });

  Route::group(['prefix' => 'analytics'], function() {

  # Analytics Dashboard
  Route::get('/', 'Analytics\Dashboard\DashboardController@index');
  Route::get('dashboard/',       'Analytics\Dashboard\DashboardController@index');


  Route::get('sales',     array('uses'=>'Analytics\Sales\SalesController@index'));
  Route::post('carDetails', array('uses'=>'Analytics\Sales\SalesController@getCarDetails'));
  Route::post('modelsales', array('uses'=>'Analytics\Sales\SalesController@getModelSales'));
  Route::post('makesales', array('uses'=>'Analytics\Sales\SalesController@getMakeSales'));


 });
```

Auth Controller Code snippet:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

 use App\User;
 use Validator;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

 class AuthController extends Controller
 {
     use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
         return Validator::make($data, [
        'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
        'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
        'username' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'designation' => 'required|max:255',
        'organisation' => 'required|max:255',
        'contact' => 'required|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
     ]);
   }

   protected function create(array $data)
   {

     $confirmation_code = md5(microtime() . env('APP_KEY'));
     return User::create([
        'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'designation' => $data['designation'],
        'organisation' => $data['organisation'],
        'contact' => $data['contact'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'confirmation_code' =>$confirmation_code
    ]);
  }

 }
```

Is it requires route configurations specific to Nginx/Ubuntu? What is the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you probably have a redirect in the url somewhere with your auth controller try logging out /auth/logout and log back in and see if you get redirected.

Comment: I don't have redirect route in my Auth Controller. I have added my Auth controller Code snippet in above post.